# insert text file into existing xlsx using Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I have a .xlsx file with 11 worksheets and I need to insert the contents of a text file (tab delim, roughly 30 columns with 100 rows) from Row 3 onwards. I tried the code below but I end up with errors. (using bash/Linux)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils import copy as xl_copy


with open('S12_final.txt') as tab_file: #open tab text file
    tab_reader = csv.reader(tab_file, delimiter='\t')
    xls_readable_book = load_workbook('S12.xlsx') #load workbook
    xls_writeable_book = xl_copy.copy(xls_readable_book)
    xls_writeable_sheet = xls_writeable_book.get_sheet_by_name('Filtered') #write data on this sheet
    for row_index, row in enumerate(tab_reader):
        xls_writeable_sheet.write(row_index, 0, row[0])
        xls_writeable_sheet.write(row_index, 1, row[1])
    xls_writeable_book.save('S12.xlsx') #save excel file
```

Errors:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./tab2excel_a.py", line 23,
> in <module>
>     xls_writeable_book = xl_copy.copy(xls_readable_book)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils-1.6.0-py2.7.egg/xlutils/copy.py",
> line 19, in copy
>     w   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils-1.6.0-py2.7.egg/xlutils/filter.py",
> line 937, in process
>     reader(chain[0])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils-1.6.0-py2.7.egg/xlutils/filter.py",
> line 61, in __call__
>     filter.workbook(workbook,filename)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlutils-1.6.0-py2.7.egg/xlutils/filter.py",
> line 287, in workbook
>     self.wtbook.dates_1904 = rdbook.datemode AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'datemode'
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems (and by no means I'm knowledgeable about those particular libraries) that you are attempting to input an [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) object into an [xlutils](http://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) method in these lines:

```
xls_readable_book = load_workbook('S12.xlsx') #load workbook
xls_writeable_book = xl_copy.copy(xls_readable_book)
```

So the interpreter complains that this "unknown" object has no attribute `datemode`. As so try using [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) [open_workbook](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.open_workbook) method since it seems to return a [Book](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.book.Book) object which, according to the documentation, is fully compatible with [xlrd.copy](http://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/copy.html#xlutils-copy) methods:

```
xls_readable_book = open_workbook('S12.xlsx') #load workbook
xls_writeable_book = xl_copy.copy(xls_readable_book)
```

Comment: Hello, trying that puts another stack of errors  `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/xlwt/Row.py", line 42, in __init__
    raise ValueError("row index (%r) not an int in range(65536)" % rowx)
ValueError: row index (65536) not an int in range(65536)`
'

Comment: What is the first line of that traceback?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tab2excel_a.py", line 24, in <module>
    xls_writeable_book = xl_copy.copy(xls_readable_book)` My file is an xlsx file, not sure if that makes any difference here

Comment: @nbn It does. xls has a specific limit of the number of rows you can have. Apparently the xlutils (or xlrd, or whatever dependencies they have), are not fully compatible with the new format xlsx. My advice is for you to re-write your code using solely openpyxl.

Comment: with openpyxl, can you copy a text file to a worksheet ?

Comment: I do not know. As I said in my answer I do not know those libraries well. I just checked their documentation based on the traceback you provided to see what the coding problem was and how to solve it. In truth you seem to need an xlsx compatible library which means ditching part of your current code (sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider this `openpyxl` example:

```
from openpyxl.workbook.workbook import Workbook # as _Workbook
import csv

wb = Workbook()
wb.create_sheet('Filtered')
ws = wb['Filtered']

with open('test/S12_final.csv') as tab_file:
    tab_reader = csv.reader(tab_file, delimiter='\t')

    # Skipt first 2 Lines
    [next(tab_reader) for skip in range(2)]

    # Append list(rowData) after Sheets last accessed Row
    for rowData in tab_reader:
        ws.append(rowData)

wb.save('test/S12.xlsx')
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***